# How display html code using a javascript function with razor (cshtml)?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, razor

I would like to display HTML code on a CSHTML page using a javascript function.

I tried to display HTML with a js function but no results

```
 <div class="col-lg-12">
  @Html.DropDownListFor(c => c.carnet.state, Model.states, new { @class = "form-control", @onchange = "showState()", id = "etat" })
</div>

<script>
  function showState() {
    return "<div class='circle enAttente'></div>";
    }
</script>
```

I would like to display any type data in HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`showState` function will return a string and this is not meaning anything. 
Do you want to insert this `div` to your `html` ?

There are so many option for do this with `javascript` and `Jquery`.

For example:

```
$('selectorOfItemWhereYouWanToPut').html('<div class="circle enAttente"></div>');
```

Comment: Exactly what i wanted! I searched complicated. So simple. Thank you!